# Length of an iframe

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I have this code on my site and it works perfectly in firefox, but chrome does not work there any way to make it work in chrome. I tried to put the iframe in Height: 95% but it is not accurate. Note: At the height of the iframe jsFiddle looks bad (do not know why)

In chrome:
[image: In chrome]

In Firefox:
[image: In firefox]

```
<html>
<body>
<header>
</header>
<nav>
</nav>
<content>
<div style="padding-left:180px;padding-top:45px">
<iframe src="http://message2space.es.vu" name="c" id="c" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</content>
</html>
<!-- and the css: --!>
header{
   z-index:100000001;
   height:45px; 
   width:100%;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#A9A9A9, #797979);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#A9A9A9, #797979);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#A9A9A9, #797979); 
   left: 0px; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px;
   background-color:#A9A9A9
}
nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10000000;
    background-color: #424242;
    height:100%;
    width:180px;
}
content{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
iframe{
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gsu2H/1/

Comment: what's the problem in chrome?

Comment: Does this work: `iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%;}`? I believe it is safer to use that than as individual attributes for the iFrame.

Comment: The problem is that Chrome does not the padding-top thanks to the iframe to fit the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the Chrome display is correct. Because you're trying to give an height of 100% and also an *offset* of 45px.

An easy solution would be using `box-sizing` to change the CSS box model for the element, so just change this line:

```
<div style="padding-left:180px;padding-top:45px">
```

To:

```
<div style="box-sizing:border-box;padding-left:180px;padding-top:45px;height:100%">
```

You want probally add a `-moz-` vendor prefix to `box-sizing` because Firefox [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) the W3C version yet.